# how to stop spinning bottle at random positions/angles in android?

Tags: android, animation

I am working on an app in which i have to spin a object like in "Spin The Bottle" app.

Rotation has been started using [RotateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation) but problem is that is stops every time at same position. I want to stop it randomly. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can create some random class for the rotation and check the time or counter, cancel the animation at that particular point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you calling the function?

The documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html

shows a few different constructors... one taking a start angle and a stop angle. All you need to do is use a random number function to generate the stop angle and pass that in:

```
    RotateAnimation(0, randomNumber);
```

Of course if you want it to start from the previous position you just need to keep that number in a separate variable and pass it in as the first parameter.

Comment: Hey! I am upvoting your answer after almost 7 years ;). Thanks mat for your answer at that time. It helped me

Comment: Ha ha, so good. I figured at first that was someone else digging out an old answer.... I'd forgotten about this!